# How do I echo a random row in PHP/MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I've been going through a number of guides on how to echo data from a random row in a MySQL database and I keep arriving at a blank page.

Here is what I believe to be the best version of code I have so far:

```
<?php $username="root";$password="notarealpassword";$database="offenders";

mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);

@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");


$sSQLQuery = "SELECT last_name AND first_name FROM offenders ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";  
$aResult = mysql_query($sSQLQuery); 
WHILE ($aRow = mysql_fetch_array($aResult)):
echo $aRow['last_name'] . " " . $row['first_name'];
ENDWHILE; 

?>
```

I have tested and made sure the connection to the database is working. Why am I arriving at a blank page and how can I fix it?

Thanks so much!

Comment: why do you close the connection before making the querry?

Comment: Because you close the connection first with `mysql_close` and then try to execute a query, also note that mysql_* functions are deprecated, look at mysqli_*.

Comment: The issue is that 'localhost' should be in quotes. Its a string literal not a variable. Also, aesthetically, I'd suggest dropping the `:`...`ENDWHILE;`  syntax and using `{`...`}`. I did VB at one time too, but thank God for C-style syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't call `mysql_close` before making queries;
2. `mysql` functions are deprecated, use `mysqli` instead;
3. I would use curly brackets instead of `WHILE - ENDWHILE`;
4. Column selected must be comma separated (not AND separated):

   ```
   $sSQLQuery = "
       SELECT 
         last_name, <- here
         first_name 
       FROM offenders 
       ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change three lines

1

```
mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password);
```

2

```
mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
```

3

```
$sSQLQuery = "SELECT last_name, first_name FROM offenders ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: The third correction is what did it. Wonder why that guide had me using 'AND'. Thanks a ton!

Comment: what guide? i seriously doubt they used AND